# Angular 6 CLI `Unknown option: '--app'`

Tags: angular

I have multiple apps in the same Angular project. After upgrading from Angular 5 to 6 when I try to run:

`ng serve --app myAppOne`

I am getting this error:

`Unknown option: '--app'`

It seems that the `--app` options is not supported any more. What is the best way to specify the app to run in Angular 6?

Comment: Did you read https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10796? Note also that [the docs](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/serve) specify `ng serve [project]`, and this is also covered on the wiki page about [having multiple projects](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-multiple-projects).

Comment: thanks, this clarified it for me

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It is not supported any more, these are the possible alternatives :

`ng serve --project=myAppOne`

`ng serve --project myAppOne`

`ng serve myAppOne`

Answer (score 1):

You can search **OldAppName** and replace with your new app **myAppOne** first, then run the project with specific port.

```
ng serve --project=myAppOne --port 4202
```

if browser is not automatically opened the url then place it manually

**http://localhost:4202**